# Add or subtract two numbers represented as Strings without using int, double, long, float, etc

Tags: c

My assignment for this question has already passed and I guess I misunderstood the question altogether by using numerical data types in some parts of my code. So I'm just curious as to how to solve this problem of adding/subtracting subtract two numbers represented as Strings without using numerical data types. By numerical data types, I just mean int, double, long, etc and everything needs to stay in String form.

Comment: What is meant by *"without using numerical data types."*? `char` is an integer type and a string is an array of `char`s, so it sounds strange

Comment: How do you add/subtract numbers by hand? You could do the same in this case.

Comment: @UnholySheep oh I'm sorry, I meant to say, without using the data types of int, double, long, etc. But everything needs to stay as a String.

Comment: @ForceBru I'm confused on how that could be done in code, can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: @Jasmine - Check this ---> [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful but that returns a double.

Comment: @Jasmine - That's how it works. You're asked to operate on string inputs. You can achieve that by converting the strings to double and int, and then perform the numerical operation. The functions are `atoi()`,`atof()` present in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @Jasmine I guess you mean that it's forbidden to convert the whole string to a number before doing calculations. Your assignment asks you to do arithmetic with individual digits and output the resulting digits one by one. Right? If yes, please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: @anatolyg No, I think the whole point of the assignment is to perform calculations without converting to a number. Which is something I don't understand how to do.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I converted my strings to int and apparently I wasn't supposed to that. But I don't know of any other way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Jasmine - You just ***can't perform numerical operations on a string `directly`, in C***

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful that's what I thought too but I missed a lot of points for converting to numbers in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that performs addition of numbers in string format into an array of `char`, assumed to be sufficiently large and different from `a` and `b`:

```
char *add_numbers(char *dest, const char *a, const char *b) {
    size_t lena = strlen(a);
    size_t lenb = strlen(b);
    size_t len = lena > lenb ? lena + 1 : lenb + 1;
    char carry = 0;        

    dest[len] = '\0';
    while (lena > 0 && lenb > 0) {
        char digit = a[--lena] - '0' + b[--lenb] + carry;
        carry = 0;
        if (digit > '9') {
            carry = 1;
            digit -= 10;
        }
        dest[--len] = digit;
    }
    if (lenb > 0) {
        lena = lenb;
        a = b;
    }
    while (lena > 0) {
        char digit = a[--lena] + carry;
        carry = 0;
        if (digit > '9') {
            carry = 1;
            digit -= 10;
        }
        dest[--len] = digit;
    }
    if (carry) {
        dest[--len] = '1';
    } else {
        for (;; len++) {
            dest[len - 1] = dest[len];
            if (dest[len] == '\0')
                break;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

No `int`, `double`, `long`, `float`.  The number is not converted into numerical format, the operation is performed one digit at a time, in string format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to do arithmetic on strings digit by digit.
Like many assignments you will get in school, there is really no point in being able to do arithmetic this way, you are just supposed to learn something about the different operations and thought patterns you would need to go through.

For addition, lets take the example `add("9","12") // returns "21"`

In order to write this function, we will do addition the same way you learned to do it in school, first the one's digit, then the ten's and so on.

to do this, we will break call an `add_digit` function once for every digit.

This function will need to take the corresponding digit from both `a` and `b` as well as any *carry* that resulted from the addition of the previous digits.

The following code is a complete example of doing this.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char * shortest(const char * a, const char * b){
  if (strlen(a) <= strlen(b)){
    return a;
  }
  return b;
}

const char * longest(const char * a, const char * b){
  if (strlen(a) <= strlen(b)){
    return b;
  }
  return a;
}

const char * add_digit(char a, char b, char carry){
   /*printf("a : %c, b : %c, carry : %c\n", a, b, carry);*/
  static char out[2] = {'0','0'};
  int a_int = (int)(a - 48);
  int b_int = (int)(b - 48);
  int carry_int = (int)(carry - 48);

  int sum = a_int + b_int + carry_int;
  if (sum > 9){
    out[0] = (sum / 10) + 48;
    sum %= 10;
  }
  out [1] = sum + 48;
  return out;
}

const char * add(const char * a, const char * b){
  const char * s = shortest(a,b);
  const char * l = longest(a,b);
  unsigned i;
  char carry = '0';
  char * out =  malloc(strlen(l) + 1);
  for (i = strlen(l); i--;){
    out[i] = ' ';
  }
  out[strlen(l)] = '\0';

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(l); i++){
    const char * digit;
    if (i < strlen(s)){
      digit = add_digit(s[strlen(s) - i - 1], l[strlen(l) - i - 1], carry);
    } else {
      digit = add_digit('0', l[strlen(l) - i - 1], carry);
    }
    carry = digit[0];
    out[strlen(l) - i] = digit[1];
  }
  out[0] = carry;
  return out;

}

int main(){
  printf("9999 + 9 = %s\n", add("9999", "9"));
}
```